# Why does my LED backlight laptop have a warning sticker about mercury?

Tags: laptop, asus-laptop, backlight, led

I recently purchased an [Asus UL30Vt-X1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002XZLURC), which according to the specs has an LED backlight for the screen. It definitely appears to be an LED backlight, but the laptop still has a sticker that the lamp in the display contains mercury.

Why is this warning sticker there if it has an LED backlight?

**Edit:** The exact wording from the sticker:

> The lamp in this display contains mercury. Recycle or dispose according to local, state and federal law.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My best guess, and it's only a guess, is that they just stick them onto all the cases anyway, and then decide whether to put a  LED backlight or a fluorescent one, or just stick them on because of inertia. Also, so that they accidentally don't leave one that needs a sticker without. It's corporate logic.

And recycling is good advice anyway. :)

Comment: Your guess is as good as any (and better than mine) +1 for corporate logic

Answer (score 0):

I belive LCD (liquid-crystal display) could not generate light on their own, so a LED was placed behind it,  then the LCD just filtered the light into different paterns, see picture here: http://byteshopstyle.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/lcd-cross-section.jpg?w=510

The LED backlight did not contain mercury, but the LCD did.

Comment: 1. The liquids used in LCDs do not contain mercury. 2. The sticker says that the lamp contains mercury.

Comment: Ignacio is correct; [LCDs don’t use mercury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_crystal#History) and the sticker specifically implicates the backlight: `The lamp in this display contains mercury. Recycle or dispose according to local, state and federal law.`

Answer (score -1):

the grimy oily filing between laptop screen in between the clear plastic and the white backdrop is a conductant of the Liquid Crystal iteself, it won't harm you but can cause skin irritation, do not get this under your finger nails, and when wiping it use an expendable towelette,  some people make mirrors out of old laptops WARNING !!!  "you should not partake in this trend with an old LCD screen" the glass is under pressure and can shatter into very fine glass airborne particals if broken" and lodge in your throat and eyes.

[PICTURE: Mirror backing of laptops][1]

Most laptops contain mercury in their display screens, it isn't a guess, it's fact,  the asus have stickers placed inside to deter any tampering by the user where you shouldn't be venturing, nobody is servicable to these areas, and if you are a recycling mob you shouldn't be manually opening these display screens, a laptop however 26''inch will not harm you unless you wipe your face in the stuff, you will get symptoms of an uneasy itch with the oily substance on your skin,

A larger LCD Screen 32" inch Tv Display can be a worry, especially with the amount of mercury, and Oily Liquid Crystals, be aware this is not water, best to wear gloves,breather mask, and  tape up the cracked screen with gap tape, cover the Set in a large waste bin bag, and tape it up, and dispose of it quickly at your Authorized E-waste recycler...there is a fee for accepting this kind of e-waste.  in this picture below you will see the most dangerous part of the laptop,  the filament light tube, this contains a high pressured vacuum of mercury.  do not touch this . [PICTURE: Filament Containing Mercury][2]

There is much more worrying parts of the laptop, such as the circuit boards  which contain in some cases Barilyum,Lead,and Arsenic, magnesium and polymer epoxy film contact that is heat shrunk over the circuits soldering points , some are greem, blue, and red....avoid handling these boards with your bare hands, and always wash when handling....Red (Cheap Asian Made) Circuit boards are banned in New Zealand and Australia, as they do not meet the Countries safety standards. [Safety Standard Logo][3]

For More Information On Mercury & other Dangers In Laptops >  [READ PDF DOWNLOAD DATA][5]

Comment: LED backlights don't have filaments.  Your "high pressurized vacuum of mercury" is for a CCFL, not LED.

Comment: The links didn't show up, probably because of your limited rep as a new user.  I see 1,2,3,and 5 (is there a missing 4?).  If you can post the links in a comment, identified by number, someone here will embed them for you.